# How do I reference an item in an array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Let's say I have something like this:

```kotlin
val arr = Array(20){it}
arr[some_very_long_function()] = 0
```

Is there any way to make a reference to this array index so that I don't have to write the function again each time?

I was thinking something like:

```kotlin
val arr = Array(20){it}
val r: Reference = arr[some_very_long_function()]
r = 0
```

I'm aware that there are a million workarounds for this problem, but this just came to my mind and I was curious.

Comment: No, this is not possible in Kotlin. As you said, there are many alternatives. I think the best you can do is by using a property delegate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious way is to keep a reference to this index:

```
val arr = Array(20){it}
val indexToChange = some_very_long_function()
arr[indexToChange] = 0
```

It is possible to do what you described by creating a class that can be used as a property delegate:

```
class ArrayPositionDelegate<T>(val array: Array<T>, val index: Int): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = array[index]

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        array[index] = value
    }
}
```

then:

```
val arr = Array(20){it}
var r by ArrayPositionDelegate(arr, some_very_long_function())
r = 0
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
I recently got into Kotlin so this might sound dumb, but what does the "T" in Array<T> mean?

Comment: The `T` is a generic type parameter. See the Kotlin docs: [Generics: in, out, where](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html). A google search for "kotlin generics" or "java generics" should turn up plenty of additional reading material.

Comment: I recommend starting by reading [the Java documentation on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), even if you aren't familiar with Java syntax. It explains the reasons for it and how it works. The Kotlin documentation is written as if they're assuming you've already used generics in some other language.